# Evaluation missing in SublimeREPL Python

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I'm trying to get SublimeREPL to work with Python. However, whenever I send a Python command to the REPL with the keyboard shortcut, only output from `stdout` is displayed. The evaluation of the command should also be displayed, but isn't. Here is a succinct example, copy and pasted from the output in the REPL after sending the commands to the REPL from Python source via the keyboard shortcut.

```
>>> print 'This will print out'
This will print out
>>> 'But this will not'
>>> 1+1
```

I would have *expected* the following output (running manually from BASH terminal in Python produces this):

```
>>> print 'This will print out'
This will print out
>>> 'But this will not'
'But this will not'
>>> 1+1
2
```

One last note, *manually* typing commands directly into the Sublime Text REPL produces the desired output, but is much slower and inconvenient.

I'm running this using SublimeText3 with the default Python 2.7.5 interpreter on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: possible dup/related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115066/display-output-from-evaluating-selection-sublime-text-python-repl

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the REPL is actually ***evaluating*** your code in the exact same manner that it would if you put all those commands in a file and ran it from the command line - it is not behaving as an interactive interpreter in this case.

If you want the REPL to behave more like IDLE, for example, you need to ***transfer*** your code to it, then switch over and run it from there, simply by adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to your key sequence. So, if previously you were using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> to evaluate a selection, just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> instead to transfer your selection to the REPL. Switch tabs and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it should behave as you are expecting.

Comment: Is there anyway do get one keybinding to both transfer and evaluation the expression? I love how in RStudio, Ctrl+Enter will transfer, eval, and even advance the cursor to the next time...

Comment: @JeffErickson in SublimeREPL's user settings, set `"show_transferred_text": true`, which means SublimeREPL will try to append evaluated code to the REPL output before evaluation. It's basically a "transfer and evaluate" all at once.